# Matlab: How do I re-insert elements in an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, insert

My original array was A = [1 0 2 3 0 7]. I deleted the indexes with a zero in them, and got A = [1 2 3 7]. I stored the indexes of the elements I deleted in an array called DEL = [2 5].

How can I re-insert the zeros in the array to get back the original array?

Answer (score 2):

This will do it for you:

```
A = [1 2 3 7];
DEL = [2 5];

n = numel(A) + numel(DEL);

B = zeros(1,n);
mask = true(1,n);
mask(DEL) = false;
B(mask) = A;
```

Alternatively, you can set the mask in one line using:

```
mask = setdiff(1:n, DEL);
```

Result:

```
B =

   1   0   2   3   0   7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [1 0 2 3 0 7] ;
A_ = [1 2 3 7] ;
[~,i] = find (A) ;
B = zeros (1,length(A)) ;
B(i) = A_ ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [1 2 3 7]; 
DEL = [2 5];

array_indices = 1:6;      % the indices of the original array
array_indices(DEL) = [];  % indices of numbers that were not deleted
B = zeros(1,6);           % created zeros of the same length as original array
B(array_indices) = A;     % replace zeros with non-zero #s at their locations
```